# Is there a reference that classifies books on grammar according to the major type of grammar the authors espouse?

Tags: resource-request

Is there a comprehensive reference that classifies books on English grammar according to the major type of grammar (reference, transformational, relational, head-driven case structure ... ) the authors espouse? This article by Richard Nordquist at [ThoughtCo.com](https://www.thoughtco.com/types-of-grammar-1689698) makes a good starting point.

This was not well received on ELU Meta, ostensibly merely because it is a request for resources (though I think that really some contributors to ELU prefer to give responses as though they were unchallengeable rather than in line with a particular analysis).

Though I can't find the equivalent of the ELU Help Center and Meta facilities here, I have been informed that requests for resources are certainly not off-topic here. And I'm sure that the knowledge that even top linguists don't agree on analyses of and approaches to understanding English, and what these schools are, how these schools differ and where a person doing research will meet a given approach, are essential prerequisites for any meaningful attempts at learning and teaching the English language.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by different types of grammar that the authors might espouse? I'm guessing it does not meat that someone likes plurals, while someone else prefers prepositions.

Comment: Thanks. Editing that into the the question would improve it.

Comment: Could you please explain in your question why it is relevant to our site (i.e. language learning or teaching) rather than [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: When you say "books on grammar", are you referring to grammars of the English language? If you are looking for grammars for a variety of languages, I think the criterion "comprehensive" will not be met.

Comment: @Christopher Strobbe _ _ adjusted.